# Association in joinData cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm creating an e-commerce website with the following tables:

```
    articles
    sizes
    colors
    orders
    articles_colors(article_id,color_id)
    articles_sizes(article_id,size_id)
    articles_orders(article_id,order_id,size_id,color_id,quantity)
```

My tables files :

ArticlesTable.php

```
    $this->belongsToMany('Colors', [
        'foreignKey' => 'article_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'color_id',
        'joinTable' => 'articles_colors'
    ]);
    $this->belongsToMany('Orders', [
        'through' => 'ArticlesOrders'
    ]);
    $this->belongsToMany('Sizes', [
        'foreignKey' => 'article_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'size_id',
        'joinTable' => 'articles_sizes'
    ]);
```

OrdersTable.php

```
    $this->belongsToMany('Articles', [
        'through'=>'ArticlesOrders'
    ]);
```

ArticlesOrdersTable.php

```
    $this->belongsTo('Articles', [
        'foreignKey' => 'article_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Orders', [
        'foreignKey' => 'order_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Sizes', [
        'foreignKey' => 'size_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Colors', [
        'foreignKey' => 'color_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

The problem is that I don't know how to get the Size and Color of the joinData in the Article object when I get an order.
Exemple :

```
$order = $this->Orders->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Articles']
    ]);
```

Result :

```
articles: [
'_joinData' => object(App\Model\Entity\ArticlesOrder) {

            'article_id' => (int) 2,
            'id' => (int) 1,
            'order_id' => (int) 57,
            'price' => (float) 100,
            'color_id' => (int) 1,
            'size_id' => (int) 2,
            //I would like to have the size and the color object
]
```

Thank you for helping :)

Comment: If you want size and color, you need to ask for it e.g. by putting those models in your contain config.

Comment: I don't know where to put those models. I tried it : `'contain' => ['Articles.Sizes', 'Articles.Colors']`  . I get Sizes and Colors associated with the Article but I don't have the Size and the Color of the _joinData. Thanks!

Comment: TBH I don't expect that to work, the property you are looking at is "join data" - you want something other than join data to be present. Rather than attempt to abuse join data, you're better off IMO changing your association definitions so that `articles_orders` is a "normal" model (such as OrderLine) with normal associations (Order hasMany OrderLine) and therefore a standard find using containable.